# TypeScript SVG import as a React Component - Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function

Tags: reactjs, typescript, svg, webpack

I'm trying to import a svg as a react component. I have installed `svgr`. Also I have added svg type definitions:

```
declare module '*.svg' {
    import React = require('react');
    export const ReactComponent: React.FunctionComponent<React.SVGProps<SVGSVGElement>>;
    const src: string;
    export default src;
}
```

The above is also included in my `tsconfig.json`

When I try to import a svg like:

```
import { ReactComponent as Logo }  from "logo.svg";

// inside render
return <Logo/>
```

It throws:

```
Warning: React.createElement: type is invalid -- expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports
```

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: why you export SVG file like `component`? and how you use `Logo`?

Comment: @Viet: Otherwise typescript doesn't know how to import `<Logo/>`

Comment: Have you found the solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure webpack in a `<something>.config.js` file in your project root directory. For example if you're using NextJS, your `next.config.js` file would look like this:

```
const nextConfig = {
    // ...
    // Enable import SVG file as React component.
    webpack(config) {
        config.module.rules.push({
            test: /\.svg$/i,
            issuer: /\.[jt]sx?$/,
            use: ['@svgr/webpack'],
        })
        return config
    },
    // ...
}

module.exports = nextConfig
```

Here's a working example ([Github](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/tree/canary/examples/svg-components)).

Answer (score -1):

If you want to use `.svg`. You just use like this.

`import Logo from "logo.svg";`

// inside render

```
<img src={Logo} />
```

Comment: Hi. I actually want to embed svg to my HTML. The way you suggest will make multiple requests to the server.